# python pandas : building a recommender (question)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

***Hello and welcome to this post, i really appreciate your help***

i'm building a food recommender, and i came accross two questions that are making me stuck :

As you can see my dataset has a column of "Ingredients", and columns for nutritional values such as sodium, proteins.. ect.

**Here is an example :**

[image]

I then created a variable full of non-vegan example of food, and if they match with the ingredients of a plate my food recommender will inform us if its is vegan free or not.

**code :**
[image]

My problem is that the ingredients in the orriginal dataset are set with quotes and my code doesn't take this into account so all meals are "vegan free". How could i fix that to take into consideration **'eggs'** and not **eggs**. Also this bunch of code takes approximatly 4 hours for me to run so could you tell me if i do nanything else wrong in the meantime before it's too late.

My second question is about making the difference between low/high calories:
By this time i have an error and don't know how to solve it at all.
[image]

**here is the error :**

[image]

**Thanks you so much in advance, here is the code for you to correct me easily:**

```
vegan = ['eggs','Castoreum','cream','cheese','Lactose','Fish','turkey','horse','MeatBeef','lamb','Gelatin','eggs','Whey']#Ect...

#It is now time to make our vegan friends happy (part 2):
for i in raw_rec_na['ingredients'].index:
    for v in vegan:
        if(v not in raw_rec_na['ingredients'][i]):
            raw_rec_na['food types'][i]='Vegan free!'
        elif(v in raw_rec_na['ingredients'][i]):
            raw_rec_na['food types'][i]='NOT Vegan free!'

#Let's now make the difference between low/high calories
raw_rec_na['calories_info'] = np.nan #creating new variable (NULL)
raw_rec_na['calories_info'] = raw_rec_na['calories_info'].astype('str')

for y in raw_rec_na['calories'].index:
    if(v < 300):
            raw_rec_na['calories_info'][y]='low in calories!'
    elif(v > 300):
            raw_rec_na['calories_info'][y]='high in calories!'
```

Answer (score 0):

In row 3 in Ingredients column the value is a list, so you have to unpack them first

Comment: how can i do that?